# Is there an e-paper library for micropython to change the font displayed on my e-paper?

Tags: microcontroller, display, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, e-ink

I'm using a 2.7 pico e-paper hooked up to a raspberry pi pico, along with a DS3231 RTC so it can display the time. I'm able to display time using the sample code provided on the waveshare page for the pico e-paper, but there's no option within the code to change font.

How can I implement font types and sizes?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The ressources of the Raspberry Pi Pico are too limited, to render a font on a screen. The only currently way to use larger fonts is to use this tool for defining a user-specified size as an python script. You load it on your device. But don't expect too large font sizes. When using this method on my large 5" Waveshare display (they sold it as Pico compatible ... well) the RAM of the Microcontroller can't store the font internally. But this should be fine with an 2.7" display.

https://github.com/peterhinch/micropython-font-to-py